# Can anyone explain why my normals have a mind of their own

Tags: modeling, mesh, normals, faces

I've tried flipping them, recalculating them and remaking the faces but i cant understand why the mesh still appears hollow, any ideas would be much appreciated
 [image: edit view]

[image: object view]

[image]

Comment: Hello, welcome. Can you share your model here http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ ? It would help to spot what's wrong. Usually, for this kind of issue, check duplicate geometry, inner faces, negative scaling...

Comment: Hi thanks for the response, i've uploaded it here [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=2066" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/2066/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normals could have nothing to do with this: I think it's just a viewport visualization issue, due to the extremely wide clip you set in this file:

[image]

that's a huge clip interval you set! from 1 mm to 10000 km!

see what happens setting it on a smaller scale, like from 1 mm to 1 km!

[image]

...your mesh is interpreted as it should... isn't it?

Explain why this happens is outside of my knowledge, but I can suggest to leave clipping limit around "reasonable" limits, depending on the scene you are trying to visualize.

Comment: Probably z-fighting when using such a wide interval. There is a finite number of z steps (not z in blender coords). When the depth is 10000km, each step becomes big (and inprecise).

Comment: Cheers for the help. I wanted my mesh to end up being around 300ft scale i guess i should've scaled it down for the blend aha